# Digital Wellbeing doesn't have timer options: detects mine device as fully-managed

Tags: custom-roms, google-play-services, android-enterprise, digital-wellbeing

I am using Nusantara ROM (Android 12) and my device is RMX2193. The device isn't managed by an enterprise so I can't understand this

Digital Wellbeing shows `App timers aren't available for work apps or fully managed devices`

Please note that app timer is no longer a Pixel exclusive feature since the last few years.

See the bottom-most part of the screenshot

[image]

Comment: What does `adb shell dumpsys device_policy` show?

Comment: Here is the output https://pastebin.com/26RnbrPf

Comment: Can you remove Google Play (or whatever name it is using) from the device administrators and see if that app timers issue is resolved?

Comment: Find My Device (part of gsf) was the only admin app on my device, I disabled the toggle fot it yet the issue persists. Also, 'Smart Lock (Google)' was a Trust Agent. I disabled that toggle too but to no avail.